# Have all the lunar landers been photographed?

Tags: apollo-program

I know that LRO photographed some landing sites. Did they get all of them? Are there still missing landers?

Comment: What about using a search machine to find out what landing sites photos are found and what are missing? If there are some missing landers anyway. So tell us which you found and which seems to be missing.

Comment: You may read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_Reconnaissance_Orbiter After doing that you may try to name missing landing sites photos. After that you should be able to answer your own question.